# Convert hierarchical Json data to flat Json with using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm now interfacing with 3rd party system.
And which are all over the world and systems are more than 1000.
I don't know how format will be.
So I'd like to parse it dynamically with setting (not changing source code one by one)

Now I'm using C# Newtonsoft.Json
And Json file contains hierarchical data.
Want to convert this to flat Json data.

Input

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "First Top",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "First child",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "value1",
              "size": "320"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dep": "First Top",
          "name": "First child",
          "model": "value2",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "First Top",
          "name": "First child",
          "model": "value3",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "First Top",
          "name": "First child",
          "model": "value4",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "First Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value1",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "First Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value2",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "First Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value3",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "First Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value4",
          "size": "320"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Second Top",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "First Child",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "value1",
              "size": "320"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dep": "Second Top",
          "name": "First Child",
          "model": "value2",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Second Top",
          "name": "First Child",
          "model": "value3",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Second Top",
          "name": "First Child",
          "model": "value4",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Second Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value1",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Second Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value2",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Second Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value3",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Second Top",
          "name": "SECOND CHILD",
          "model": "value4",
          "size": "320"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Third Top",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "First Child",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "value2",
              "size": "320"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dep": "Third Top",
          "name": "First Child",
          "model": "value3",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Third Top",
          "name": "First Child",
          "model": "value4",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Third Top",
          "name": "First Child",
          "model": "value5",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Third Top",
          "name": "Second Child",
          "model": "value1",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Third Top",
          "name": "Second Child",
          "model": "value2",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Third Top",
          "name": "Second Child",
          "model": "value3",
          "size": "320"
        },
        {
          "dep": "Third Top",
          "name": "Second Child",
          "model": "value4",
          "size": "320"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Output

```
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "First child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "First Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Second Top", "name": "SECOND CHILD", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "First Child", "model": "value5", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value1", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value2", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value3", "size": "320" },
    { "dep": "Third Top", "name": "Second Child", "model": "value4", "size": "320" }
```

I had tried to do with looping dynamically but couldn't succeed.
I think, it is needed to do it by recursive calling method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recursive, or stack / queue. There are 2 problems here essentially, I think if you could first deseralize this to concrete classes and provide them, someone would whip up a method for you pretty quickly.

Comment: Both JSON you showed are identical.....  The only change I see is indentation... I am not sure what you mean by "flat json"... there is only json.... May be if you explain a bit more about what you are actually trying to do.  If all you want to do is remove indentation that is easy.

Answer (score 1):

The **Newtonsoft.Json** library supports [LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm), so you can quite easily flatten collections using C#'s `SelectMany()` (as well as the many other LINQ operators).

For example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var input = "{ 'name': 'root', 'children': [ { 'name': 'First Top', 'children': [ { 'name': 'First child', 'children': [ { 'name': 'value1', 'size': '320' } ] }, { 'dep': 'First Top', 'name': 'First child', 'model': 'value2', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'First Top', 'name': 'First child', 'model': 'value3', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'First Top', 'name': 'First child', 'model': 'value4', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'First Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value1', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'First Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value2', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'First Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value3', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'First Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value4', 'size': '320' } ] }, { 'name': 'Second Top', 'children': [ { 'name': 'First Child', 'children': [ { 'name': 'value1', 'size': '320' } ] }, { 'dep': 'Second Top', 'name': 'First Child', 'model': 'value2', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Second Top', 'name': 'First Child', 'model': 'value3', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Second Top', 'name': 'First Child', 'model': 'value4', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Second Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value1', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Second Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value2', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Second Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value3', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Second Top', 'name': 'SECOND CHILD', 'model': 'value4', 'size': '320' } ] }, { 'name': 'Third Top', 'children': [ { 'name': 'First Child', 'children': [ { 'name': 'value2', 'size': '320' } ] }, { 'dep': 'Third Top', 'name': 'First Child', 'model': 'value3', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Third Top', 'name': 'First Child', 'model': 'value4', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Third Top', 'name': 'First Child', 'model': 'value5', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Third Top', 'name': 'Second Child', 'model': 'value1', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Third Top', 'name': 'Second Child', 'model': 'value2', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Third Top', 'name': 'Second Child', 'model': 'value3', 'size': '320' }, { 'dep': 'Third Top', 'name': 'Second Child', 'model': 'value4', 'size': '320' } ] } ] }";

var root = JObject.Parse(input);
var rootChildren = (JArray)root["children"];
var flattened = rootChildren.SelectMany(child => ((JArray)child["children"]).Skip(1)); // Skip the first one as it's irrelevant for the output.

// Create a JArray from the flattened collection (of JTokens)
// to be able to easily output it as a JSON string.
var jArray = new JArray(flattened);
var output = jArray.ToString();
```

You'd notice that I'm skipping the first child of the 2nd nesting of `children`. I've only done this to match your expected output which for some reason didn't include the first child of each nested collection.

As an example of what you could do with this solution (given the requirement for a dynamic level of nesting), consider the following example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ikM1Ov

In this example, I've modified on your original input, wrapping the `name` and `size` fields in their own object and I've put them in a new level of `children` nesting (I've also removed the skipping of the 1st child).

Comment: Hi eitamal, thanks for your kind help. This will be greatly helpful to me. In my case, I can't expect its child node name will be "children" always. And some of case, there could be 2nd 3rd nested or more. Would there be possibility to do it dynamically satisfying all these case too?

Comment: That should be possible. The rules you've provided are a bit vague. If the name isn't "children", would it be different in the different nestings, i.e. `{ "a": [ { "b": [ { "c": [ { "v": 1 } ] } ] } ] }`? How do you determine the array to flatten (e.g. is it all sub-arrays, or just the first, etc.)? Also, how would you explain missing that first child (i.e. where I've used `Skip(1)`)? Should it just skip the first child of the last nesting or is it the first child of every array? The list of questions can go on and on. Once they're clear, the solution should be pretty clear also :)